# C++ std::max acting like std::min

Tags: c++, max, min

Note: This is for the problem [teleportation](https://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=807) from usaco.org (hence the strange variable names, I'm obviously not making an actual teleporter)

When I try using the built-in max for (2, 8), and I get 2 for some reason. I also created my own functions like this:

```
#define min(number_1, number_2) (number_1 < number_2 ? number_1 : number_2)
#define max(number_1, number_2) (number_1 < number_2 ? number_2 : number_1)
```

but it still fails. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define min(number_1, number_2) (number_1 < number_2 ? number_1 : number_2)
#define max(number_1, number_2) (number_1 < number_2 ? number_2 : number_1)

int main() {
    int start_position, end_position;
    int teleportation_start_position, teleportation_end_position;

    cin >> start_position >> end_position >> teleportation_start_position >> teleportation_end_position;
    cout << start_position << " " << end_position << " " << teleportation_start_position << " " << teleportation_end_position << "\n";

    start_position = min(start_position, end_position);
    end_position = max(start_position, end_position);

    teleportation_start_position = min(teleportation_start_position, teleportation_end_position);
    teleportation_end_position = max(teleportation_start_position, teleportation_end_position);

    cout << start_position << " " << end_position << " " << teleportation_start_position << " " << teleportation_end_position << "\n";
}
```

And I get with the input of

```
3 10 8 2
```

I get

```
3 10 8 2
3 10 2 2
```

Why is it 2 2?

It still doesn't work when I delete the things I defined (#define).
I only inserted a code snippet.

Note #2: I'm new to c++ with mostly pythonic habits.

Comment: Don't `#define` a name that is also used in the standard library (and try to avoid macros in general; there is no need for one here; a function would do as well). That technically causes undefined behavior and will practically cause chaos if you include a standard library header after the macro definition.

Comment: `Why is it 2 2?` because you compare `2` with `2` in the last `max` statement

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you stepped through this code in a debugger, it should be obvious as to where things go awry.

Comment: Even going through this on paper, making notes to keep track of the value of each variable should reveal quickly why the result is what it is.

Comment: You could remove about 80% of that code and still get the problem. Just assign values to `teleportation_start_position` and `teleportation_stop_position` and remove all the code that's no longer used. After you've done that, if you still don't see the problem, post the newly-shrunken code.

Comment: Very very bad idea to  blindly use ``using namespace std;`` **and** define some random macro as ``max`` and ``min``

Comment: @Pranav When you reach the line `teleportation_end_position = max(teleportation_start_position, teleportation_end_position);`, what are the values of `teleportation_start_position` and `teleportation_end_position`?

Comment: @Borgleader -- no, the `min` and `max` macros are implemented correctly.

Comment: How should I change the min and max calls?

Comment: Note that macros are really simple, awesomely stupid text substitution. They do no sanity checks, they just blindly replace when they find a match. You're almost always better off using a function.

Comment: @Pranav *When I try using the built-in max for (2, 8), and I get 2 for some reason* -- That's not possible.  If `std::max(2,8);` returns 2, then thousands of C++ programmers who use your compiler, and hundreds if not thousands of companies who use the compiler, would have reported the issue.  In addition, the compiler vendor would be embarrassed at such a silly error, maybe even enough to sully their brand.  Instead of creating macros, you should have figured out why you got the result using `std::max`.

Comment: I didn't know that it was from the previous variable results @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that you are re-using the `teleportation_start_position` variable.

```
teleportation_start_position = min(teleportation_start_position, teleportation_end_position);
```

Before this line the state of your program is:

- `teleportation_start_position` = 8
- `teleportation_end_position` = 2

But after, it is:

- `teleportation_start_position` = 2
- `teleportation_end_position` = 2

So in the next line you are doing:

```
teleportation_end_position = max(teleportation_start_position, teleportation_end_position);
// teleportation_end_position = max(2, 2);
```

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: Variables are free! So just use a new one to store your min/max values.